# Prototyping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototype

I am learning a javascript and while I was go through it I was learning `prototyping` so i tried following code

```
function vehicle(type,year){
    this.type="moped";
    this.year="2012";
}
Activa=new vehicle;
console.log(Activa.type);
console.log(Activa.year);

function speed(km){
console.log(km);
}
vehicle.prototype.speed=speed;
console.log('160km/hr');
```

The above code gave me the proper and correct output

**But**

when i was trying varient of it of it it doesnt gave me the proper output

following is the code

```
function vehicle(type,year){
    this.type="moped";
    this.year="2012";
}
Activa=new vehicle;
console.log(Activa.type);
console.log(Activa.year);

function speed(km){
 km="160";
 console.log(km);
}
vehicle.prototype.speed=speed;
console.log(Activa.speed);
```

The above code gave me the following(snap shot of chrome console) output in chrome developer tool

[image: Output in console]

whats wrong am i doing?and why it gave me the output like in the image the output I am expecting is 160

Comment: i guess you want to do `console.log(Activa.speed());`

Comment: no it gives undefrine the output should be 160

Comment: You know the difference between a function call and a function reference? Also, most likely you want your method to return a value too.

Comment: Were are you learning Javascript?.  It's not forced upon you, but normal convention for Javascript is that class function start with a capital letter, and instance vars start lowercase, so in your example, I would have `Vehicle` not `vehicle` and `activa` and not `Activa`.   Also don't forget to define your vars, eg.  `var activa=new Vehicle;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues with your code

- Parenthesis missing with the `speed()` method in  `console.log(Activa.speed);`
- your `speed()` method is not returning anything that why you are getting undefined

Try something like below

```js
function vehicle(type, year) {
  this.type = "moped";
  this.year = "2012";
}
Activa = new vehicle;
console.log(Activa.type);
console.log(Activa.year);

function speed(km) {
  var km = km || "160";
  console.log(km);
  return km;
}
vehicle.prototype.speed = speed;
console.log(Activa.speed());
```

- One more issue is the you are trying to replicate class type behavior in JS then you should stick to standard, base function should have first character capital, something like below -

```js
function Vehicle(type, year) {
  this.type = "moped";
  this.year = "2012";
}
var activa = new Vehicle;
console.log(activa.type);
console.log(activa.year);

function speed(km) {
  var km = km || "160";
  console.log(km);
  return km;
}
Vehicle.prototype.speed = speed;
console.log(activa.speed());
```

For more details follow here - http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: @Maddyplusplus It is a null check. If you aren't passing any values, it takes the default value as `160`.

Comment: @ what if you want to pass some custom speed in that case it will override the default speed which is `160`

Comment: @pradeep1991singh  `it will override the default speed`  no it won't.. the || stands for OR, so if the first value is not null, or 0.. etc.  if won't evaluate the second due to boolean shortcut.  try this in console. `100 || 50`, you will get 100, but if you did `0 || 50` you will get 50.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal,

You are referencing speed as a function

```
function speed(km){
 km=km||"160";
 return km;
}
```

So you should log speed like that

```
console.log(Activa.speed());
```

and not like that

```
console.log(Activa.speed);
```

And you will have your correct output (160)

Comment: but `console.log(Activa.speed());` gives undefine

Comment: Don't downvote for nothing... You can see in this jsfiddle the correct output (160): https://jsfiddle.net/qj8vfdy0/

Comment: @GilleQ. Your answer is incorrect, you aren't returning the value, just logging it.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I did not see the console.log in the function. Answer edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Activa.speed is a function so if you use

```
console.log(Activa.speed());
```

it will output what you expect.

functions are also variables in javascript so console.log(Activa.speed); outputs the content of the variable, which in this case is a function.